# How to make class accessor to private in Framework(Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode7

I create a `cocoa touch framework` and language is **objeciveC**

Some files as the following:

Staff.h

```
 @interface Staff : NSObject
-(void) say:(NSString *) text;
@end
```

Staff.m

```
@implementation Staff
-(void) say:(NSString *) text{
    NSLog(@"%@",text);
}
@end
```

Company.h

```
#import "Staff.h"

@interface Company : NSObject
@property(nonatomic) Staff *Staff;
@end
```

I want Company.h is public and Staff.h is project, and setting as the following:
[image]

Finally, build the framework and using it in an app demo, and get error as the following in the demo

[image]

How should i set the framework?

Comment: Don't import `Staff.h` in `Company.h`.  Use `@class Staff` in the header and do the import in `Company.m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't import `Staff.h` in `Company.h`. Use `@class Staff` in the header and do the import in `Company.m`.